# Obter uma Interface de um Type

Tags: vb.net, interface

Quero ver se um `Type` é implementado pela interface `System.IDirectOutput` e acessar seus métodos, mas não sei como, estou tentando isso:

```
 If GetType(IDirectOutput).IsAssignableFrom(Expression) Then
      Return CType(Expression, IDirectOutput).InstanceOutput
 Else
      Throw New InvalidOperationException($"The specified type is not implemented from {NameOf(IDirectOutput)}.")
 End If
```

mas não funciona :(. Me ajudem!

> Atualização

Tentei esse método e funcionou: (*em resposta do qmechanik*)

```
 If TypeOf Expression Is IDirectOutput Then
     'statements...
 End If
```

Comment: Já tentou usar o [`TypeOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18.aspx)? `If TypeOf IDirectOutput Is Expression Then`.

Comment: Isso que acabei de tentar :P

Comment: :D em C#, se você tiver interesse, dá para fazer (*não testei*): `if (typeof(IDirectOutput).IsAssignableFrom(Expression)) { ... }`

Comment: Pode ser, não gosto de programar em C# mesmo :P

Comment: Postei uma resposta, quando for possível, eu coloco um exemplo verificável.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A documentação do [método `Object.GetType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.object.gettype(v=vs.110).aspx) sugere que seja usado o [operador `TypeOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18.aspx) para verificar se um objeto corresponde a um determinado [*tipo*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.type(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
 If TypeOf Expression Is IDirectOutput Then
    Return CType(Expression, IDirectOutput).InstanceOutput
 Else
    Throw New InvalidOperationException($"The specified type is not implemented from {NameOf(IDirectOutput)}.")
 End If
```